# how in pandas groupby custom sort columns by value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and i try the results from Groupby export to excel by custom sort values one , two or more columns :

- id sorted by `['bv','cl','an']`
- color sorted by `['blue','red','orange','green']`

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'color': ['green', 'red', ' orange', 'red','blue',' orange', 'red','blue', 'red', ' orange', 'red','red','green'],
        'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','bob','Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','nick','Tom'],
        'form': [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','b', 'c', 'd','d','e','b', 'c', 'b'],
        'id': [ 'an', 'bv', 'cl', 'cl','an','bv', 'an', 'cl','cl', 'an','bv','bv','an'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

df_1 = df.groupby(['color','Name','id'])['form'].agg('count')
print(df_1)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')    
df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

print(' I try the df to excel have custom sort values in columns')
print('id sort by [bv,cl,an]')
print('color sort by [blue,red,orange,green]')
print('how can make it?')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*Categorical Data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) then [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) :

```
ids = pd.CategoricalDtype(["bv", "cl", "an"], ordered=True)
colors = pd.CategoricalDtype(["blue", "red", "orange", "green"], ordered=True)
#add here more categories if needed

out = (
    df.astype({"id": ids, "color": colors})
        .groupby(["color", "Name", "id"], observed=True)["form"].agg("count")
        .sort_index(level=[0, 2]) #in case, add here more levels
)

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
    # add here a custom styling/formatting if needed
```

Output :

```
print(out)

color   Name   id
blue    krish  cl    1
        bob    an    1
red     jack   bv    1
        nick   bv    2
        jack   cl    1
        nick   cl    1
               an    1
orange  Tom    bv    1
        krish  cl    1
               an    1
green   Tom    an    2
Name: form, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Τhank you!!! thank you very much...!!!
I want to ask you one more if you can help me...
is there a way to prioritize the result to get the  excel with first the red that has more subcategories in the name column (5) then the orange (3) and then continue with the name column and its subcategories .
from largest to smallest

Comment: You're welcome ;) And regarding your second question, I think it would be better if you [open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new one.